# What does 1 attack-speed point mean in League of Legend?

Tags: league-of-legends

What does 1 attack-speed point mean - does it mean 1 second per auto attack?
And 0.5 attack-speed points mean 0.5 second per 2 auto attack?

[image]

Comment: Don't get into arguments in comments. Users are more than welcome to ask about questions which already have answers on wikis, and users are also free to downvote if they feel a question is lacking in research. Finally, and I'm getting tired of saying this: [Be nice](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This number indicates the **frequency** of your auto-attacks. Having 0.625 means you "attack 0.625 times in 1 second".

In other words, it means that you attack every `1 / 0.625 = 1.6` seconds.